# Bad performance of angularJS in Firefox

Tags: javascript, angularjs, performance, firefox, web

I have huge performance issues with my angularJS app using Firefox (V45).
I'm not able to find the problem. It works perfectly in Google Chrome, IE11 and Edge.

Does someone know how get better overall performace in Firefox?

Nochmal auf Deutsch:
Ich habe gewaltige Performance Probleme mit meiner AngularJS App. Diese treten nur im Firefox auf. In andern Browsern gibt es keine Probleme.

Hat jemand eine Idee wie man die Performance steigern kann?

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing your code is hard to tell what's wrong. But most of the time when there is a performance problem with angular application, means that you have to many watchers (data bindings). You can use this chrome extension to analyze if you can remove some of them https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/angularjs-batarang-stable/niopocochgahfkiccpjmmpchncjoapek. Google is full of pages with tips how to optimize your website. Most popular are cutting down number of observables and using one-way data bindings (http://blog.thoughtram.io/angularjs/2014/10/14/exploring-angular-1.3-one-time-bindings.html).

Comment: There are only 56 watchers. And I have only issues with Firefox. It runs perfectly in Chrome.

The performance problems occur when I compile new content to the DOM. After the content is inserted, I use jQuery.show().
Firefox seems too slow with rendering the new content.

Comment: From my experience angular apps generally works slower in ff. I don't know firefox dev tools that much, but maybe they have something similar to chrome profiler? It could help you to find the bottleneck of your app. Also why you're using jQuery.show(). Maybe you could use just ng-show binding?

Answer (score 1):

Turning off firefox devtools rises performance significantly! ;)